# Individual post. Meta_key, taxonomy or post status for separation?

Tags: taxonomy, exclude, post-status, meta-value

I have a posts with custom type - TOUR. Among ordinary Tours sometimes I need to create "personal" or "private" Tour, which will be shown only to assigned user.

What the way is better to exclude this "private" Tour from others and not show it in the Tours list.
Threre are meta_value, taxonomy or post_status options.